# Клиент с WCF, которому нужны права администратора

Tags: c#, http, веб-сервер, wcf, client

По задаче необходимо с сервера необходимо перенести http сервисы WCF в клиент. Перенести перенес, однако данным службам необходимы права администратора. Клиент не имеет прав администратора и получить их не сможет никак. И суть проблемы я понимаю: что нужно зарегистрировать http адреса на прослушивание c помощью:

`netsh http add urlacl url=%URL% user=%USER%.`

Но как уже сказал прав администратора никто давать не будет, а данная команда выполняется только под ними.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли избежать как-то регистрации адресов на прослушивание (что вряд ли) либо есть какие-нибудь альтернативные варианты?

P.S. переносить сервисы с сервака на клиент тупо, знаю. Но такая задача.

Comment: Пишите инсталлятор. Один раз на компе установили - потом можно будет запускать клиент без проблем. Ну а инсталлятор пусть админы сами думают, как расставить - либо политиками, либо логонскриптами, либо ещё как.

Comment: Попробуйте слушать `http://0.0.0.0:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/ваш_суффикс`

Comment: Если Skype не "отберёт" порт - должно работать

Comment: Сервис запускается, но не реагирует на запросы при этом.

Comment: А на других машинах все нормально, только у меня не реагирует на запросы. Возможно из-за RDP. Так что способ рабочий, спасибо:

`http://0.0.0.0:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/%LOCALOATH%`
OR
`http://localhost:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/%LOCALOATH%`

OR

`http://localhost/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/%LOCALOATH%`